# Get updated date value on outside container click in bootstrap date picker inline (Combodate )

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, bootstrap-datepicker

I am using date picker of bootstrap x-editable. Its working fine but I want to customized some of it's functionality. Suppose when we select any date and click on Tick mark then we can show the combined date inside a tag. So I want to get the same functionality onblur also (outside of the container but date should be change).

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) - it would help if you can post the code that you've tried so far or even create a fiddle. And how is C# (that you've tagged) related to your question?

Comment: @Vivek What do you mean by combine date,could you give an example

Comment: https://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/demo-bs3.html?c=popup please go on Combodate (date) part.

Comment: @http://jsfiddle.net/jjdJX/3/ its for textbox and I am using date picker instead of text. But functionality would be same.

Comment: @mpf82 If you don't know then why you are making argument. Is there any restriction that C# developer can't give answer of this question.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use this code into your input text as like that

```
<input size="16" type="text" value="2012-06-15 14:45" readonly class="form_datetime">

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".form_datetime").datetimepicker({format: 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:ii'});
</script>
```

Comment: <a href="#" class="boldfont" id="inline-dob" name="inline-dob" data-type="combodate" data-value="@Model.GUST_StartDate.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")" data-format="MM-DD-YYYY" data-viewformat="MM/DD/YYYY" data-template="MMM / D / YYYY" data-pk="1"  data-title="Select Date of birth">

Comment: you can add this code <span class="input-xs-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></span> below your input,I think it will help you